# Unmanaged Switch No Longer Recognizing Internet Connection

Tags: switch

I have an unmanaged switch providing an internet connection to several items in my entertainment center. It has worked without issue for months. We had a thunderstorm come through with a lightning strike near the house (I know because it traveled up one of the sprinkler zone control wires into the sprinkler controller and burned out the driver FET). We then noticed nothing in that entertainment center had an internet connection. I unplugged the Cat6 cable from the switch and plugged it directly into the AppleTV which immediately recognized an internet connection. I then replaced the Cat6 cable into the switch - no internet. I plugged it into several different RJ45s on the switch, still no internet. I brought in another switch I had lying around and it works - everything sees an internet connection through it. I ordered another of the same, nonworking switch (TRENDnet TEG-S80g 8-port switch) thinking the lightning strike did something to it. The new one behaves exactly the same as the one that stopped working. For reference, all devices connected show constant activity on the LEDs, but the connection to the router will show activity for maybe half a second, and then nothing for 5-7 seconds and repeat that loop over and over.

The connection diagram is: router > large unmanaged switch (providing LAN connections throughout the house) > small unmanaged switch (the one that’s not working) > end devices

Any thoughts? I’m at a loss since the router, large unmanaged switch, Cat6 cable in the wall, and Cat6 cable from the wall to the entertainment center all seem fine and provide an internet connection. Also, the placeholder switch works while the brand new TRENDnet doesn’t (just like the old TRENDnet).

Comment: Obvious suggestion: Have you rebooted the router after replacing the switch?

Comment: Not entirely consistent with your statement of events, but could you have a routing loop of some sort caysing ports to shut down?

Comment: Wow, that’s embarrassing. I’d rebooted it before, but decided I’d do it again to make sure everything came up in good order. That’s when I realized I never power cycled the big unmanaged switch for the house. Rebooted everything in order, working my way out from the router, and now everything works. We must’ve had a power outage and everything came back fine except the one port servicing the entertainment center. Weird. Thanks for getting me to double check my work!